# Cómo toma valor la variable format en el bloque del método mail de ActionMailer en Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo una duda.  Usando el método mail de ActionMailer en ocasiones usan un bloque y recibe un objeto format.  Cómo toma valor ese objeto para determinar si se envía el email en HTML o en TXT?

```
mail(to: @user.email,
   subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site') do |format|
   format.html { render 'another_template' }
   format.text { render plain: 'Render text' }
end
```

Gracias.

Comment: Envía ambos formatos (txt y html), el cliente de correo toma el formato que soporte (o esté configurado) y lo muestra.

Comment: Secundo lo dicho por Gerry. Para confirmarlo, por ejemplo en gmail, al abrir un correo te sale una opción "Mostrar original" donde podrás encontrar una parte `Content-Type: text/plain` u otra que diga `Content-Type: text/html`, cada una con los textos que agregaste al email.

Comment: Excelente respuestas.  Muchas gracias.